# I am trying to create a pause screen ontop of my playscreen (where the user plays the game)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to create a pause screen in java with libgdx.

My issue is that i am trying to create the screen on-top of the play screen so when the user presses the button 'p' the game will be paused; the state of the game will remain the exact same as to where the user has left off and when they click the resume button, they will be brought back to the play screen, resuming the current state of the game.

Right now i have implemented a pause screen, where the user clicks 'p' and they will be sent to a completely new screen where a resume button is displayed. Now when the user clicks resume it does send the user back to the play screen but it completely restarts it for them. For some reason its not going back to the state they left it in.

Any help would be very much appreciated. T

Comment: "For some reason its not going back to the state they left it in." - the reason is that you are creating this screen from beginning. You should either somehow serialize the state of the screen and then load this or use some trick to "freeze" game, cover with this pause screen and then uncover and let it run again

Comment: "for some reason" We can tell you what that reason is exactly if you show your code. But if you want your pause screen to be transparent to your game screen you'll need to either do your own custom Game class that can draw multiple screens at once or put all your pause functionality into the same Screen as your game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your LibGDX app you are replacing your active screen, which destroys the previous one.

If you are pausing your game, and you don't want to navigate away from your game screen, you can set up a boolean (isPaused) in your game screen. If this is true, do not update your game elements and render your pause menu. If false, your game updates.

Advantage: This means you don't have to save all your game data as it is still in memory.

Disadvantage: Your pause menu will be more of an overlay component rather than it's own screen, but to the user this can still look however you want. ;)

Comment: Hi Robert! 

I am new to java programming so please do forgive me if i seem "stupid" but, would it be something along the lines of:

if(isPaused == true)
{
//EMPTY
}
else{
//RUN RENDER CODE
}

Comment: Yes! You can do something like if(is Paused) {renderPauseMenu()} else { renderGame()} and apply the same logic to your update loop.

Comment: Cheers pal, appreciate it. ive managed to get my head around that now. The only issue im having now is that whenever i press 'P' for the pause menu, it does appear but it appears behind everything else on screen... 

Any reason as to this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is an issue with the order in which you are rendering. If you want the pause menu to render over your game, you should put it last in your render method. render() {renderGameWorld() if(isPaused) renderPauseMenu()}